# Serializing object then deserialize as list<object> C#

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, serialization, deserialization, bin

I'm stuck in this problem and I've been searching anywhere for answers but didn't found something that fits my problem. I want to serialize object and save it into a binary file, and `deserialize` it as list since it will returning multiple rows of records.

So, this is my class

```
[Serializable]
public class DTOMultiConfig
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string KeyValue { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class DTOMultiConfigs : List<DTOMultiConfig>
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
    }
}
```

and I'm using these methods I found online. This is how I serialize my object, this part works

```
public void Editor_Config(DTOMultiConfig dto)
{
    if (dto.ID == 0)//new
    {
        dto.ID = 0;
        WriteToBinaryFile(BinPath, dto, true);
    }
    else//edit
    {
    }
}

public static void WriteToBinaryFile<T>(string filePath, T objectToWrite, bool append = false)
{
    using (Stream stream = System.IO.File.Open(filePath, append ? FileMode.Append : FileMode.Create))
    {
        var binaryFormatter = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();
        binaryFormatter.Serialize(stream, objectToWrite);
    }
}
```

This is how I use the `deserialize` method, I'm not sure , I'm sure I'm doing it the wrong way because it's not working at all. The `ReadFromBinaryFile` stops working right before the 'return' statement.

```
public PartialViewResult ShowListOfConfigs()
{
    List<DTOMultiConfig> dto = new List<DTOMultiConfig>();

    //DESERIALIZE  

    dto = ReadFromBinaryFile<List<DTOMultiConfig>>(BinPath);
    return PartialView("_ListOfConfigs", dto);
}

public static T ReadFromBinaryFile<T>(string filePath)
{
    using (Stream stream = System.IO.File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open))
    {
        var binaryFormatter = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();
        return (T)binaryFormatter.Deserialize(stream);
    }
}
```

Any answers with some explanation will be appreciated.

Comment: What's the exception you're getting? I suspect your problem is that you write a single DTOMultiConfig instance but attempt to read a List<DTOMultiConfig> which cannot work since the binary representation of a single instance of your type is different than the binary representation of a list.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the response, I'm getting this exeption {"Unable to cast object of type 'MVCHowTo.Models.DTOMultiConfig' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MVCHowTo.Models.DTOMultiConfig]'."}

Comment: so, should I make my dtoMultiConfig a list when writing to a binary file as well? Because I write with only 1 record at a time,

Comment: Yes, absolutely. See my response below. And you won't be able to incrementally add elements to the file if that is what you intend to do.

Comment: Got it working! thanks.. the problem is it's only returning 1 record, I wrote to bin twice, so it should return two rows...I set the parameter 'append' to true, Am I missing something?

Comment: See my response below. Appending one element to a file once will *not* give you the representation of a list. I'll edit my answer below to explain that a bit better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me try to explain. Imagine you weren't using a binary serializer but instead an XML Serializer. In this case what you'd be writing would look kind of like this:

```
<DTOMultiConfig>
  <Key>SomeKey</Key>
  <Value>SomeValue</Value>
</DTOMultiConfig>
```

Now, when you read your data back, you are attempting to deserialize your single instance into a List which, however, would need to look somewhat similar to this:

```
<ListOfDTOMultiConfigs>
  <DTOMultiConfig>
    <Key>SomeKey</Key>
    <Value>SomeValue</Value>
  </DTOMultiConfig>
  [...potentially more elements here...]
</ListOfDTOMultiConfigs>
```

That simply cannot work. In a binary world, the actual data in the file would look different. However, the same problem persists: You cannot write one type and read a different one back unless their structure is absolutely identical.

In order to deal with you concrete case you could read back a single element and then put it in a list if you need the list. Or your could write a list with a single element to your file and then read that list back using your above code.

**EDIT:**

In your comment above you say that you'd expect that writing a single element twice to the file should give you a list. Going back to my example above, writing a single element twice would give you this:

```
<DTOMultiConfig>
  <Key>SomeKey</Key>
  <Value>SomeValue</Value>
</DTOMultiConfig>
<DTOMultiConfig>
  <Key>SomeKey</Key>
  <Value>SomeValue</Value>
</DTOMultiConfig>
```

If you compare this to my example for the representation of a list above you will see that they are not identical and hence cannot be used interchangeably.

Comment: Ok, I'll try writing it as a list and I'll let you know. Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, I actually wrote a list<dtomulticonfig> on the file twice... but it's only returning a single record

Comment: This is my update code : List<DTOMultiConfig> _dto = new List<DTOMultiConfig>();
                _dto.Add(dto);
                WriteToBinaryFile(BinPath, _dto, true);

Comment: I'm inserting a list as a parameter to WriteToBinaryFile method, set append to true, hmmm Do I need to get the current value of my bin , save it to a list then add my object into it, and use it on my Writetobinaryfile method? is that how 'Append' works?

Comment: "Append" just means that the writer will not overwrite the existing contents of the file. It will "append" its data to the file. I don't think you really want this. I suggest you always first deserialize everything in your file first (that should be one single list with a certain number of elements) then append to your list or change it otherwise. And finally you write the entire list to your file again *without* using "Append". So at any given point in time your file's contents will be just one list.